# What does the word “short” mean in “two feet short”？

Tags: meaning

This is from Randall Jarrell’s *[The Bat-Poet](http://www.apelslice.com/books/0-00-BRITE/1-880323-06-0/series5sem1.htm)*:

> “Oh yes,” said the mockingbird. “**And it was clever of you to have that last line two feet short.**”
>
> The bat said blankly, “Two feet short?”
>
> “It's two feet short,” said the mockingbird a little impatiently. “The next-to-the-last line’s iambic pentameter, and the last line’s iambic trimeter.”
>
> The bat looked so bewildered that the mockingbird said in a kind voice, “An iambic foot has one weak syllable and one strong syllable; the weak one comes first. That last line of yours has six syllables and the one before it has ten; when you shorten the last line like that it gets the effect of the night holding its breath.”
>
> “I didn’t know that,” the bat said. “I just made it like holding your breath.”

[image]

Comment: Same thing as it means in *"a day late and a dollar short."* What about it is confusing?

Answer (score 4):

The "feet" here are poetic feet—units of rhythmical meter that collectively make up to a full line of poetry. If the rest of a poem consists of lines of five [iambs](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iamb) (or iambic feet) each ("da DA da DA da DA da DA da DA"), a line that consists of only three iambs (""da DA da DA da DA") is "two feet short." (Note that *pentameter* refers to verse consisting of five poetic feet per line, whereas *trimeter* refers to verse consisting of three poetic feet per line.)

Comment: These are also called "metrical feet", which reminds me of the expression "metric ton" or "metric tonne", but that's silly.